# Сериализация строки в строку. JsonSerializer

Tags: c#, .net-core

Есть generic методе `Foo<T>`, в котором есть такая строка:

```cs
var responseObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(stringData);
```

в некоторых случаях необходимо сделать вызов: `Foo<string>()`. В этом случае я получаю ошибку:

> The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.

Подскажите, есть ли вариант заставить сериализатор понять, что от него требуется?

Comment: А как выглядит тот JSON, который не преобразовывается?

Comment: @aepot Возвращается массив объектов, а объекты могут быть разные: `"[{...}, {...}]"`

Comment: Как вы ожидаете, что массив объектов будет десереализован в строку? Что вы хотите получить на выходе?

Comment: чтобы он вернул то, что в него передели без изменений

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>` не умеет возвращать строку, которую в него передали без изменений

Вместо этого можете попробовать вот такое заклинание

```csharp
T responseObject = typeof(T) == typeof(string) ? (T)(object)stringData : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(stringData);
```

Comment: Да, вот не очень хотелось бы юзать магию. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: никакой магии нет. просто метод не умеет обрабатывать строки, возможно и другие примитивные типы (только массивы и словари). может это и правильно, они же формально не являются json.